# access to the path is denied asp.net in iis

Tags: asp.net, iis

i want to save file upload file in 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Content\SpeechFile\' in visual studio i can save this files

```
if (file != null)
            {
                string urlfile;
                string path = Server.MapPath("~" + "\\Content\\Apk\\");
                string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                while (System.IO.File.Exists(path + "\\" + filename))
                    filename = "1" + filename;
                urlfile = "../../Content/Apk/" + filename;
                file.SaveAs(path + filename);
                model.Fileurl = urlfile;
            }
```

but on server i have an error

**Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Content\SpeechFile\nokia 700.jpg' is denied.**

Comment: If you newly created the folder "SpeechFile" then please check the access rights on it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.net Getting the error "Access to the path is denied." while trying to upload files to my Windows Server 2008 R2 Web server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724297/asp-net-getting-the-error-access-to-the-path-is-denied-while-trying-to-upload)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the user account the application pool runs under will not have permissions to write to any sub-folders for security reasons. You will have to check which user your application runs under and then give that user write permissions to the `SpeechFile` folder. Make sure that is the only folder that you do give it write permissions to so that the security risk is minimised.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to solve this problem is to not write to that folder. You are not allowed to write to that folder .Just Tried to Give `Access Rights` to your Folder `SpeechFile`.

You may also use [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) to help you find where you need to go.