# ASP.net Getting the error "Access to the path is denied." while trying to upload files to my Windows Server 2008 R2 Web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.0, windows-server-2008-r2

I have an asp.net webapplication that uploads files to a specific folder on the Web server. locally everything works fine, but when I deploy the application to the Webserver, I begin getting the error "Access to the path "D:\Attachments\myfile.doc" is denied". I gave the "IIS AppPool" user that the application is running under full permission on the folder. I even gave "Everyone" full permissions, but with the same error.

I added the folder to the Exceptions list of the Antivirus, but with the same result. I am begining to suspect that maybe Windows Server 2008 R2 needs a trick for my upload to work. I really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Your asp.net account `{MACHINE}\ASPNET` does not have write access to that location. That is the reason why its failing.

Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity.

Right click on downloading folder `Properties > Security Tab > Edit > Add > locations > choose your local machine > click OK > Type ASPNET below "Enter the object name to select" > Click Check Names`
Check the boxes for the desired access (`Full Control`). If it will not work for you do the same with `Network Service`

Now this should show your local `{MACHINENAME}\ASPNET` account, then you set the write permission to this account.

Otherwise if the application is impersonating via `<identity impersonate="true"/>`, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically `IUSR_MACHINENAME`) or the authenticated request user.

---

Or just use dedicated location for storing files in ASP.NET which is `App_Data`. To create it right click on your ASP.NET Project (in Visual Studio) `Add > Add ASP.NET Folder > App_Data`. Then you'll be able to save data to this location:

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/file.txt");
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, "Hello World");
```

Comment: Thanks Damian, I didn't try this yesterday at the server. I will have access to the server again on sunday morning, then i will test and get back to you if it worked, Thanks again :)

Comment: I tried it on my local machine but couldn't find the account ASPNET on my local machine

Comment: Dear Damian, I couldn't find the user named "ASPNet" on the local machine, also setting the location to AppData didn't work :(

Comment: It worked after i gave IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool wirte permissions over the App_Data folder. It also worked when i gave the "Network Service" permissions on the folder

Comment: I've just spent hours on this and it turned out that the path was wrong - exact same error!

Comment: @IrishChieftain same thing got me too.

Answer (score 89):

Right click on your folder on your server or local machine and give full permissions to

IIS_IUSRS

that's it.

Comment: After checking of increasing permissions of Network Service this worked for me, Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

the problem might be that networkservice has no read rights

salution:

rightclick your upload folder -> poperty's -> security ->Edit -> add -> type :NETWORK SERVICE -> check box full control allow-> press ok or apply

Comment: Useful if unable to get IIS_IUSRS

Answer (score 3):

If anyone stumbles across this as it is the first result in google,

remember to specify the filename too in the SaveAs method.

Won't work

```
file_upload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(SaveLocation));
```

You need this:

```
filename = Path.GetFileName(file_upload.PostedFile.FileName);
file_upload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(SaveLocation + "\\" + filename));
```

I assumed the SaveAs method will automatically use the filename uploaded.
Kept getting "Access denied" error. Not very descriptive of the actual problem

Comment: Not a helpful error message for this behavior at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I faced this problem once and in my case the soln is **to close any process in the task manager that uses/accesses that file**.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked under Advanced Security Settings?

something like below image change permissions of folder to IIS_IUSRS

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late to the game, but I wanted to share in case it helps someone.

Your exact situation may not apply, however I had a similar situation and setting the File attribute helped.

Try to set the File attribute to Normal:

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/file.txt");
File.SetAttributes(path, FileAttributes.Normal);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, "Hello World");
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: @SRoy - Are you trying to write to App_Data or some other path?

Comment: Thank you for this, I've been pulling my hair out for 3 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Verify what are you attempting to write. I was having the same issue, but I realized i was trying to write a byte array with length of 0.

It doesn't make sense to me, but I get: "Access to the path "

Answer (score -5):

Go to root folder

Right Click, click on Properties

Choose Tab Security

Click on Edit

Click on Add

Type 'EveryOne'

Click OK

Check Out Full Control

Click OK

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and follow the guideline there to provide quality answer.

Comment: We should have disable Firewall too along with giving machine name password to everyone.

Comment: Giving Everyone full control is NEVER the answer.