# In ASP.net I am getting error Access to the path '~\Upload\1_myimage.png' is denied?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have uploaded my website on server when i try to save image on uploaded folder called Upload then it gives error

**Line 114:        {
Line 115:            string str = imagepath;

Line 116:            fuStudentPhoto.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/" +str));
Line 117:            Image = str;**

I gave all permission rights to Upload folder but still its stuck here. Help me anyone to solve this issue...

Comment: have you build your solution after the permissions

Comment: and also instead om imagepath you need to pul filename

Comment: no no...will do it...and let you know...thanks :)

Comment: also give image name not imagepath

Comment: Its not working can you please explain me with small example :) if possible for you???..it will  be really helpful for me :)

Comment: can you tell me the exact error?

Comment: you should give file name i will give youy an example

Comment: you should use path.combine not concating

Comment: here i am using file upload control (fuStudentPhoto) the code you can see 
below :

**
 public static int i=1;
 string image='" ";
if (fuStudentPhoto.HasFile)
        {

            string str = i.tostring() + "_" + fuStudentPhoto.FileName;
            fuStudentPhoto.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/" + str));
            Image = str.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Image = "N";
        } **

Comment: use  Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/Upload/", str))

Comment: Still its giving same error...

Comment: can you tell me the exact error?

Comment: the same error still there...

string str = lbltext.Text.ToString() + "_" + fuStudentPhoto.FileName;
Line 117:            //fuStudentPhoto.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/" + str));
Line 118:            **fuStudentPhoto.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/Upload/", str)));**
Line 119:            Image = str.ToString();
Line 120:        }

Comment: can you write me the error?

Comment: Thanks you so much :)

Comment: what was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Give full permissions for user IIS_IUSRS for your 'Upload' directory on server.

Answer (score 0):

in your action [HttpPost]
    your input will be `HttpPostedFileBase file` and you input type file should have name="file" then:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
```

in your .net controller

```
var filename = Sytem.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/Upload/", filename)));
```

do not forgot to put enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form

Answer (score 0):

> **Line 114: { Line 115: string str = imagepath; Line 116: fuStudentPhoto.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/" +str));
>   Line 117: Image = str;**

The above will not work and you will have to replace it with

```
filename = Path.GetFileName(file_upload.PostedFile.FileName);
file_upload.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(SaveLocation + "\\" + filename));
```

Do remember to specify the filename too in the SaveAs method.

Credit: [ASP.net Getting the error "Access to the path is denied." while trying to upload files to my Windows Server 2008 R2 Web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19724297/asp-net-getting-the-error-access-to-the-path-is-denied-while-trying-to-upload)

Comment: Will try and let you know :)

Comment: @SurajBinorkar ok

Comment: @suraraj Binokar then accept the answer and close question.